# How to convert GeoJSON Feature Collection object to Pandas dataframe without geometry

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON feature collection object including a bunch of Features, where each feature has a geometry and properties. Because the geometry includes all the coordinates, which results in large and not required data, I would like to skip the geometry and extract only the properties. How can I achieve this?

I tried with
`df = pandas.json_normalize(<my-feature-collection>.features)`

The structure of my Feature Collection is as follows. I want to keep properties for each feature, but ignore geometry.
[image]

Comment: `properties` is a dict of scalar values or can contain list/dict as values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If properties contain only scalar values a simple comprehension can do the job:

```
df = pd.json_normalize([feat['properties'] for feat in data['features']])
print(df)

# Output
    prop0  prop1
0  value0    NaN
1  value0    0.0
2  value0    1.0
```

Minimal reproducible example:

```
>>> data
{'type': 'FeatureCollection',
 'features': [{'type': 'Feature',
   'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [102.0, 0.5]},
   'properties': {'prop0': 'value0'}},
  {'type': 'Feature',
   'geometry': {'type': 'LineString',
    'coordinates': [[102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0], [104.0, 0.0], [105.0, 1.0]]},
   'properties': {'prop0': 'value0', 'prop1': 0.0}},
  {'type': 'Feature',
   'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
    'coordinates': [[[100.0, 0.0],
      [101.0, 0.0],
      [101.0, 1.0],
      [100.0, 1.0],
      [100.0, 0.0]]]},
   'properties': {'prop0': 'value0', 'prop1': 1}}]}
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks! how would one proceed if the properties does not only contain scalar values, but again a dict/list as values?

Comment: In this case, what do you want to do? If you use the code as is it the new columns will be prefixed by the parent key like `prop0.propA`, `prop1.propB`.